# Dispose of MessageBodyStream won't abort reading

Tags: c#, wcf, stream, dispose

I use WCF to transfer **CSV** documents. I have a scenario where I only want to read the first line of the file. After I did this I want to dispose the `Stream` provided by the `WcfChannel` which is of type: `MessageBodyStream` and has a `StreamedMessage` as child.

> The problem is that the `MessageBodyStream` it's dispose will wait for
>   the stream to be read entirely.

**Example code:**

```
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();

try
{
    var stream = channel.ReadCsvFile();
    channel.Close();

    var line = ReadFirstLine(stream);
    stream.Dispose(); // <-- here hangs the runtime
}
catch
{
    channel.Abort();
}
```

**What I researched:**

- Read the code of the `MessageBodyStream`.
- Searched for this problem in depth.
- Changed the order of closing (channel and stream).

Am I doing something wrong? What is the standard solution to tackle this problem?

[Source: MessageBodyStream](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Dispatcher/StreamFormatter.cs,c42d1f57ef8092d2)